# GCP pricing confusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I've created a VM instance with GPU, which I want to utilize for deep learning and intense image-related operations.

My setup is: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=1dc86e0d-1d42-45e2-aafb-9da6731eaf06

The calculator telling, that the monthly cost will be around 284$ , but it also states that *"Pay for what you use: no upfront costs and per second billing"* When I am creating a VM instance.

Additionally, to be more confused, I was checking the billing, and after the first full day, the billing cost for yesterday is more than 11$ , which is much more than 284$ when you multiple 11x 30(days). Also, the compute engine was used only for few test runs, it's not even in production stage.

Can I get some explanation / clarification here?

I was trying to speak with the tech support, but it's always cutting the connection and I am too tired to start over and over again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the end of the billing period, Google applies discounts for continuous usage. That is why the daily charge is more than the monthly charge. You are charged while the instance is running. It does not matter if you are using it or not. If you do not want to be billed either shut down the instance or delete it.

Comment: @JohnHanley , thanks for your answer, really appreciate it! So to clarify: Every day it will be 11-ish $$$ , when the instance is online, regardless its being used non stop, or just running "empty" ? But i am still confused about the "Pay for what you use: no upfront costs and per second billing"  part..

Comment: If you create an instance, you are reserving resources. That means you pay for those resources. Delete the resource when it is no longer required.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley! Have a nice day! I will update this thread once I've got my first invoice

Answer (score 0):

Each vCPU and each GB of memory on Compute Engine is billed separately rather than as part of a single machine type

[Sustained use discount](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#sustained_use) of up to 30% is applied when resources deployed are used for more than 25% of a month and are not receiving any other discounts.

You can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sustained-use-discounts) as reference

Comment: I will see in one week. For now, the prices are horribly high :) I am using 2x Nvidia Tesla with the Computing engine, I've also realised that I am paying also for static IP address reservation.

Comment: I got no discounts at all, could it be a reason that I am using geocoding API with discount as well? I've paid almost 400$ last month, btw there is also an extra cost for the ingress network traffic which was not mentioned in the "calculator"